# Utilizar valores array para hacer varios INSERT INTO sql php

Tags: php, sql, array

Estoy tratando de crear varias inserciones a la vez en la que lo único que cambia es un valor.

Tengo un formulario con el que selecciono 1 asignatura, 1 examen, un desplegable con lenguajes (español, ingles, etc.) y una fecha de activación.

He creado un select multiple para que muestre los diferentes lenguajes y poder seleccionar varios a la vez y guardo las opciones que elijo en:
name="lenguaExamenId[]"

```
<select name="lenguaExamenId[]" id="lenguaExamenId" multiple>
<option disabled selected value="">Seleccionar</option>
        <?php foreach($lenguas as $lengua) { ?>
               <option <?php echo $asigExamen->lenguaExamenId === $lengua->id ? 'selected' : ''; ?>    
                     value="<?php echo s($lengua->id); ?>"> <?php echo s($lengua->nombreLengua); ?> 
               </option>                  
        <?php  } ?>
 </select>
```

Para poder obtener cada uno de los id de las lenguas he hecho un foreach y he transformado el string en un int.

```
    $lenguas = $_POST['lenguaExamenId'];
    foreach($lenguas as $lengua => $l)
        $lenguas[$lengua] = intval($l);
```

Por último realizo una consulta para poder realizar la inserción de los datos, pero es aquí donde me está dando error y no estoy sabiendo encontrarlo.

```
    $query="INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen (asignaturaId, examenId, lenguaExamenId, fechaActivarExamen)";
    $query.=" VALUES ('" . $_POST['asignaturaId'] ."', '" .$_POST['examenId'] . "', (" .implode(',',($lenguas)) . "), '" . $_POST['fechaActivarExamen'] ."') ";
```

Al realizar la inserción me sale esté problema:

INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen (asignaturaId, examenId, lenguaExamenId, fechaActivarExamen) VALUES ('26', '13', (2,3), '2022-11-18')

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

¡Gracias por el tiempo de echarle un vistazo!

Comment: El problema es que estás produciendo el valor para `lenguaExamenId` así: `(2,3)`, ¿podrías decirnos de qué tipo es la columna `lenguaExamenId` en la tabla?

Comment: Si, la columna lenguaExamenId es una Foreign Key de tipo int. Como comentaba, me gustaria en el caso del ejemplo, crear 2 registros donde se mantenga la misma informacion menos lenguaExamenId. Un registro que tenga el 2 y otro registro que tenga el 3.

Comment: Eso no quedaba claro en la redacción de la pregunta. Revisa el segundo caso expuesto en mi respuesta, creo que es eso lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No queda claro si la columna `lenguaExamenId` es del tipo `VARCHAR` y debe aceptar una lista de valores numéricos. De ser así, aunque es un pésimo diseño, puedes hacerlo de este modo:

```
$asignaturaId=$_POST['asignaturaId'] ?? null;
$examenId=$_POST['examenId'] ?? null;
$fecha=$_POST['fechaActivarExamen'] ?? null;
$lenguas=$_POST['lenguaExamenId'] ?? null;

if ($asignaturaId && $examenId && $fecha && $lenguas) {
    $list = implode(",",array_map('intval', $lenguas));
    $query=sprintf("INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen  
                    (asignaturaId, examenId, fechaActivarExamen, lenguaExamenId) 
                    VALUES (%d,%d,'%s','%s')",
                    $asignaturaId,$examenId,$fecha,$list); 
    echo $query;      
} else {
    echo "Hay datos vacíos, revisa el formulario";
}
```

Ahí tendrás una salida más o menos así:

```
INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen  
        (asignaturaId, examenId, fechaActivarExamen, lenguaExamenId) 
        VALUES (9,7,'2022-11-10','2,3')
```

Nótese que he mejorado algunas cosas, por ejemplo, no conviene ir al trapo a buscar valores en `$_POST` sin saber si existen, exponiéndote a casos de *`Undefined index`*.

Si de lo que se trata, en cambio, es de insertar `N` filas según la cantidad de valores en `lenguaExamenId`, entonces podrías resolverlo de este modo:

```
$asignaturaId=$_POST['asignaturaId'] ?? null;
$examenId=$_POST['examenId'] ?? null;
$fecha=$_POST['fechaActivarExamen'] ?? null;
$lenguas=$_POST['lenguaExamenId'] ?? null;

if ($asignaturaId && $examenId && $fecha && $lenguas) {
    foreach ($lenguas as $lengua) {
        $query=sprintf("INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen  
                    (asignaturaId, examenId, fechaActivarExamen, lenguaExamenId) 
                    VALUES (%d,%d,'%s',%d)",
                    $asignaturaId,$examenId,$fecha,(int)$lengua);
        echo $query.PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "Hay datos vacíos, revisa el formulario";
}
```

Dentro del `foreach` se producirán consultas como esta que deberás ir ejecutando:

```
INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen  
        (asignaturaId, examenId, fechaActivarExamen, lenguaExamenId) 
        VALUES (9,7,'2022-11-10',2);

INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen  
        (asignaturaId, examenId, fechaActivarExamen, lenguaExamenId) 
        VALUES (9,7,'2022-11-10',3);
```

O puedes optar por escribir una sola consulta de inserción. Algo así:

```
$asignaturaId=$_POST['asignaturaId'] ?? null;
$examenId=$_POST['examenId'] ?? null;
$fecha=$_POST['fechaActivarExamen'] ?? null;
$lenguas=$_POST['lenguaExamenId'] ?? null;

if ($asignaturaId && $examenId && $fecha && $lenguas) {
    $query="INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen  
                    (asignaturaId, examenId, fechaActivarExamen, lenguaExamenId) 
                    VALUES ";
    $values="";
    foreach ($lenguas as $lengua) {
        $values.=sprintf("(%d,%d,'%s',%d),",$asignaturaId,$examenId,$fecha,(int)$lengua);
    }
    $query.=trim($values, ",");
    echo $query;
} else {
    echo "Hay datos vacíos, revisa el formulario";
}
```

Cuyo resultado será:

```
INSERT INTO asignaturaExamen 
    (asignaturaId, examenId, fechaActivarExamen, lenguaExamenId)
VALUES 
    (9,7,'2022-11-10',2),
    (9,7,'2022-11-10',3);
```

Esto tiene la ventaja de ser **una sola consulta** que ejecuta **varias inserciones**. De todos modos, para este caso debes pensar también en la seguridad, implementando consultas preparadas, pues tu código queda expuesto a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Lee sobre el tema en cuanto sea posible.